# unknown publisher windows setup file when run this

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I create a setup project in visual studio. The exe file is redistributale,  The problem is that when i run the setup file it display .

[image: Information window]

Can anyone help to make this proper for any user

Comment: What version? Visual Studio has not had installer projects since.. 2010 I think. What software are you using?

Comment: @nvoigt i am using VS 2005 for create setup file

Comment: Wow, that's.. old. I'm sorry, I don't have anything installed that's that old :)

Comment: @nvoigt in Visual studio 2015 also you can create Installer Project, The extension is available in Visual Studio online Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

If you Authenticode-sign the .msi file, Windows will show the signature details in the UAC consent dialog. For example, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/22/authenticode-code-signing-for-developers-for-file-downloads-building-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx.